# SharePoint 2010 Workflow task is not being delegated Using Nintex Workflow 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, workflow, nintex-workflow

[image: Workflow Image is attached]Please Help...

I have created workflow in SharePoint 2010 using NintexWorkflow 2010. In workflow I am using delegate task action to delegate the current task to other ManagerB if ManagerA is not available to approve the task.

I am saving the ActionID in a Variable and using the same variable to delegate the task in delegate task Action.

***Problem:*** When the workflow is running the delegate task action is being executed but the task is not being delegated to the ManagerB.

Any suggestions / solutions are welcome.

Thanks in adavance.